# C# GetSpoolFileHandle Api Call => "A StartDocPrinter call was not issued" Error

Tags: printing

In my C# project, I'm catching printjobs. After pausing them I want to get a file stream to spool file associated with a printjob(I know printerName and jobId).

This is the way I'm trying to get s spool file.

1) OpenPrinter("PrinterName, Job XXX", ref hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero) //XXX is the jobId,

No Problem here. I'm getting hPrinter.

2) IntPtr spoolFileHandle = GetSpoolFileHandle(hPrinter);

spoolFileHandle returns Intptr(-1) and lastWin32Error says "A StartDocPrinter call was not issued"

All I want to do is : Get spoolFileHandle, get a file stream from that handle, read&write to stream, CommitSpoolData, CloseSpoolFileHandle and last ClosePrinter.

What I'm doing wrong? (I dont want to find spl file by myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetSpoolFileHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/getspoolfilehandle) function retrieves a handle for the spool file associated with the job currently submitted ***by the application***. If a job was started by the application, the application would call [StartDocPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/startdocprinter) before calling GetSpoolFileHandle. The GetSpoolFileHandle cannot be used to retrieve a file handle from a job submitted by another application.

The Windows Print Spooler API does not provide an interface to intercept print jobs submitted by other applications.